# discord.js ubuntu } catch { SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: ubuntu, bots, discord.js

Hey i want to run my bot on my ubuntu server and there is the error if someone find it

```
/root/minecraft/le_vallfeur/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:41
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/minecraft/le_vallfeur/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js:8:11)
```

But that work in visual studio.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are unable to help you unless you provide the source code of your bot. Thank you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Provide your scripts whatever you have done so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a because the node version is out of date,

Try catch block used to always require an error parameter like so:

```js
try {

} catch(error) {

}
```

But optional catch binding was suggested and implemented:

```js
try {

} catch {

}
```

The only problem is that this requires node version 8 or above, so to fix you need to simply update your node.js

After you fix that though there might be another error underneath, depends on your code, which you will need to show